# php - codeigniter, how to get multiple query and counted it from model

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm new on Codeigniter. and I'm trying to get my model to return two queries, one for the data itself which is a few notes from the table, and the calculation field. and returns the output of the form (very good, good, and bad). with the poll where he relates to officer_name. the problem is when I use count(*) from three different query the result is only null.


 this is the query from my model.

```
$this->db->select('a.id_poll')
                ->select('a.poll')
                ->select('a.date')
                ->select('a.id_officer')
                ->select('b.officer_name')
                ->select('c.id_service')
                ->select('c.service_name')
                ->select('count(a.poll) as verygood')
                ->where('b.officer_name', $officer['officer_name'])
                ->where('a.poll','verygood')
                ->select('count(a.poll) as good')
                ->where('b.officer_name', $officer['officer_name'])
                ->where('a.poll','good');
                ->select('count(a.poll) as bad')
                ->where('b.officer_name', $officer['officer_name'])
                ->where('a.poll','bad');
$this->db->from('tbl_poll as a');
$this->db->join('tbl_officer as b', 'a.id_officer = b.id_officer');
$this->db->join('tbl_service as c', 'b.id_service = c.id_service');
return $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

This is output I wanted:

```
Officer_name | Service |        Polls          |
             |         | Verygood | Good | Bad |
Bella        | Payments|    3     |  2   |  1  |
Christy      |   CS    |    5     |  3   |  0  |
ETC.         |   etc   |    3     |  3   |  3  |
```

Can somebody help me and how to do this, or a fix for my current code?

Thank you in advance!

*sorry my English was so bad*

Here is the
[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f479ce/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, may help.

```
$this->db->select('a.id_poll,a.poll,a.date,a.id_officer,b.officer_name,c.id_service,c.service_name,count(a.poll) as verygood,count(a.poll) as good,count(a.poll) as bad');
$this->db->from('tbl_poll as a');

$this->db->join('tbl_officer as b', 'a.id_officer = b.id_officer');
$this->db->join('tbl_service as c', 'b.id_service = c.id_service');

$this->db->where('b.officer_name', $officer['officer_name'])
$this->db->where('a.poll','verygood')

$this->db->where('b.officer_name', $officer['officer_name'])
$this->db->where('a.poll','good');

$this->db->where('b.officer_name', $officer['officer_name'])
$this->db->where('a.poll','bad');

$query = $this->db->get();

$result = $query->result_array();

//To check the resutl for test purpose only

echo "<pre>";  print_r($this->db->last_query()); echo "</pre>";  // To check the query
echo "<pre>";  print_r($result); echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: The result is =  {
    "id_poll": null,
    "poll": null,
    "date": null,
    "id_officer": null,
    "officer_name": null,
    "id_service": null,
    "service_name": null,
    "verygood": "0",
    "good": "0",
    "bad": "0"
}

Comment: @Ariakun can you please database table structure or can you please create SQL fiddle so I can get what exactly you want to do?